# Google Cloud SQL: Alter table: ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table xxx

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to alter a table in a Google Cloud SQL database that has several million records and has couple of indexes on it.

After a while (during which the space used on the db instance goes up by several GBs), the "alter table" command fails with the error: "ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table xxx".

1) I searched for it and it seems that it often happens when the tmpdir goes short of space. The suggestions seemed to be that change the location of tmpdir for the MySql database to some place on file system where more storage is available. I don't really have that option on Google Cloud SQL setup, as far as I know.

2) I ran a "check table xxx" command on the mentioned table and it showed status=OK. So, there is no real corruption of the table involved anywhere. It just seems to be going short of space behind the scenes in the "alter table" on this heavy table.

Any suggestions please? Can I increase the tmpdir space on Google Cloud Sql setup for my project somehow? Can I change its location and give it more space somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Cloud SQL First generation instance specific problem. Location or allocated amount of tmpdir storage (10 Gb) cannot be changed in that case, unfortunately.

The only reasonable option would be to migrate to Cloud SQL Second gen instance:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-2nd-gen

Comment: No, it's already a Cloud SQL Second generation setup. Did you mean that if it's second-gen, location or allocated amount of tmpdir storage can be changed? How?

Comment: v1 has rigid limit in place due to service architecture, while v2 should be able to grow tmp directory all the way to the maximum allocated disk space of the instance. Can you confirm that you're not running out of total disk space allocated to the instance during ALTER TABLE execution?

Comment: I am confirming that I am not running out of total disk space. In fact, I am left with almost 25% of total capacity still free when I run into the error I reported / when it hits the peak during the execution of the command. Also, I have tried the command multiple times and it has failed with this error without going anywhere close to exhausting the total disk space.

Comment: I suggest you to file an issue under non-public component (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901) and mention your project and instance id. GCP team will look into specific instance details potentially causing this.

Comment: I have reported it on the issue-tracker u pointed to. Let's see. Thanks.